# Is it possible to mix tenses when using "after" or "before"?

Tags: conjunctions

Is it possible to mix tenses when using "after" or "before"?

**Example 1**

scenario: He won the championship in the past. He will make a lot of money in the future.

> After he won the championship, he will make a lot of money.

can it be reduced to

> After winning the championship, he will make a lot of money.

**Example 2**

scenario: He is training a lot, and he will compete against other players next month.

> He is training a lot before he competes against other players next month.

**Example 3**

scenario: He learned how to solve types of math questions in the past, and he will take an exam in the future.

> He learned how to solve such math questions before he takes the exam.

Comment: The first version of Example 1 invalidly mixes tenses - it should be *After he won the championship, he **would** make a lot of money.* There's nothing wrong with Example 2, but Example 3 is also invalid - as with #1, it should be consistently Past throughout: *He learned how to solve such math questions before he **took** the exam.* OR you can cast the initial clauses to Present: ***After he wins...*** and Present Perfect ***He has learned how to...*** if you want to keep Future / Present for the secondary clauses.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "After he has won the championship, he will make a lot of money." - Does this sentence mean the action of winning was in the past, and in the future he will make lots of money? "After he wins the championship, he will make a lot of money." - this one sounds like the winning will happen in the future to me, tho. Would you explain a bit?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. *After he has won the championship, he will make a lot of money* strongly implies *He **hasn't yet** won it* (but speaker *expects* he will win). That's a kind of "Present Perfect in the Future" construction that usually means exactly the same as "Present in the Future" *After he wins...*. Note that what's often called the "Present Participle" can be used to refer to a Past, Present, OR Future win: *After **winning** the contest ... he **was / is / will be** very proud*.

Comment: ...note that the continuous form can also be used to refer to a *hypothetical* (perhaps even *impossible*) action that's not specifically located in the Past OR the Future: *After building a perpetual motion machine, I **would be** able to retire as a very rich man.*

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with "After winning the championship, he will make a lot of money" it is not specifically understood that at this stage he actually *has* won the championship. It merely states that *when* he has won it, he will make that money.

It is, by this wording, assumed that indeed he *will* win the championship at some stage.

What I would say is:

- "Now he has won the championship, he will make a lot of money."

If you are talking about the past, you would say:

- "After winning the championship, he made a lot of money."

But the answer to the question is that you *don't* mix tenses like this, it feels wrong.

Comment: I agree with what you say about Example 1, but I find Example 2 acceptable. I would use _he has learned_ in Example 3.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes apologies, it's an incomplete answer because I got interrupted by a domestic distraction, and I left it where it was. Soz.